# Azure App Registration Change Homepage Url

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory

I have a web app that which, when I have created and "Application Registration" has picked up the default url as https://localhost:44338/

[image]

This field is greyed out and I am unable to change it.

In a Microsoft document it suggests that I can change the url in the "Branding" tab. Their example looks like this:

[image]

But, when I go to the Branding page in my portal it looks like this:

[image]

Can anyone advise how I can change that url to the public one of the website please?

Comment: How did you get to the branding page? I have the same one as the sample.

Comment: First of all: what type of Azure Active Directory are you using? There are some distinct differences between Azure AD and B2C. Then, if you're using the 'normal" AAD, which tier are you using? They have quite distinct differences, too.

Comment: @rickvdbosch It appears that it's a B2C AD

Comment: @TonyJu AD > App Registrations (Preview) > Select the App > Branding

Comment: @TrevorDaniel I see, for Azure B2C AD, you can change the signInUrl in Mainfest.

Comment: @TonyJu Perfect! Many thanks. Please add this as an answer so i can mark it correct and give you kudos!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sample you referred to is a application in Azure AD. For Azure B2C AD, you can change the value in Manifest file.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The example you found is for the 'normal' version of Azure Active Directory. The screenshot you posted of your *Branding* blade shows the branding blade for an **Azure AD B2C** app registration, as you already mentioned.

Have a look at the Manifest blade, you can update the URL from there, under `signInUrl`.

[image: The Manifest blade]